# How to construct diagonal above the main diagonal using numpy and python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate an array A defined as

```
A = [[1, 2, 0], [3, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1]]
```

I have tried to construct it as

```
A = np.diag(np.ones(3), k=0)
```

What should I do to construct the diagonal above the main diagonal? if I mention k=0 it returns the values of diagonal above the main diagonal

Comment: can you try to specify exactly how the values are determined? what exactly is the rule here? e.g. why is the bottom diagonal 3 but the upper is 2, and top-right corner is 0 but bottom-left is 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) and some [2-d slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) to fill diagonals that are not the main one.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.diag(np.ones(3), k=0)
np.fill_diagonal(A[1:, :], np.ones(3) * 3)
np.fill_diagonal(A[:, 1:], np.ones(3) * 2)
print(A)
```